# normalize column data with maximum value of that column

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a data file with two columns. I want to find out the maximum data value from the second column and divide each entries of second column witht he maximum value. (So I will get all the entries in second column <= 1.00).

I tried with this command below:

```
awk 'BEGIN {max = 0} {if ($2>max) max=$2} {print  ($2/max)}' angleOut.dat
```

but I get error message as below.

```
awk: (FILENAME=angleOut.dat FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

note: There are some data in the second column which is zero value. But when the zero value divide with max value, I should get zero, but I get error as above.

Could I get any help for this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The logic is incorrect in this because it wont find the maximum from second column where as will divide the number by a maximum number which it as seen so far ( this seen maximum may not be the actual maximum in the second column ) Provide some sample input and excpected output for more clarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take this as the sample input file:

```
$ cat >file
1 5
2 2
3 7
4 6
```

This awk script will normalize the second column:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{max=($2+0>max)?$2:max;next} {print $1,$2/max}' file file
1 0.714286
2 0.285714
3 1
4 0.857143
```

This script reads through the input `file` twice.  The first time, it finds the maximum.  The second time is prints the lines with the second column normalized.

#### The Ternary Statement

Consider:

```
max=($2+0>max)?$2:max
```

This is a compact form of an if-then-else statement.  The "if" part is `$2+0>max`.  If this evaluates to true, the value following the `?` is assigned to `max`.  If it is false, then the value following the `:` is assigned to `max`.

The more explicit form of an `if` statement works well too.

Also, note that incantation `$2+0`.  In `awk` variables can be strings or numbers according to context.  In string context, `>` compares lexicographic ordering.  We want a numeric comparison.  By adding zero to `$2`, we are removing all doubt and forcing `awk` to treat `$2` as a number.

Comment: Thanks for the help. By the way, could you explain a little the meaning of "($2+0>max)?$2:max". I am curious to know this for my understanding.

Comment: @Vijay Your welcome.  Also, I added a section on ternary statements to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot determine max before seeing the whole file so you need two passes. This one uses two `awk` executions to get the normalized output:

```
awk -vmax=$(awk 'max < $2 { max = $2 } END { print max }' angleOut.dat) \
    '{print $2 / max}' angleOut.dat
```